# Spatial reference in Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

So, I have the following code to write onto a report the spatial reference of a feature class. My workspace (geodatabase) contains, 3 feature classes; studyarea, destination, and source. For some reason, when I run this code, it only gets the spatial reference for source feature class and write that onto the report for all 3 feature class. What change do I need to make so that my code gets a spatial reference for each of these 3 feature classes?

[image]

```
def data_report(workspace):

    elements = defaultdict(list)

    walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True)

    filename_dict = {}

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
        for dirname in dirnames:  # 'FeatureDataset'
            desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname))
            elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

        index = 0
        for filename in filenames:
            desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)


    report = []

    for element_type, element_list in elements.items():
        report += [f"{element_type}:"]
        for element_description in element_list:

            if element_type == "FeatureClass":
                spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)).spatialReference
                report += [f"\t\t\t\tSpatial reference: {spatial_ref.name}"]
```

Comment: Your code has invalid indentation and many undefined references.

Comment: I just did not post the whole code, but I have defined everything in this code. They are not just on here. Indentention, I will fix it later

Answer (score 1):

The following code is wrong.

```
if element_type == "FeatureClass":
    spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)).spatialReference
    report += [f"\t\t\t\tSpatial reference: {spatial_ref.name}"]
```

The correct code should be:

```
if element_type == "FeatureClass":
    spatial_ref = element_description .spatialReference
    report += [f"\t\t\t\tSpatial reference: {spatial_ref.name}"]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gave me the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryuma\OneDrive\Desktop\ARCtest2.py", line 144, in <module>
    report = domain_report(workspace) + data_report(workspace)
  File "C:\Users\ryuma\OneDrive\Desktop\ARCtest2.py", line 70, in data_report
    spatial_ref = element_description .spatialReference
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'spatialReference'
 Failed to execute (Script3).

Comment: I can't run your code, but you can print **element_description**, then choose the right way to get **spatialReference**. Good luck!